# Extract the body of a response in JMeter and use in other requests

Tags: jmeter

I want to extract the entire response body of a request and pass it to a variable. Using this variable I want to use it in other requests.

I want to use 11857 number in other requests using some variables:
[image]

Comment: Could you please share the response body and which portion you are intended to extract from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract using JMeter [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) (Right click on Sampler and choose Add)

`Boundary Extractor` is irrelevant because you don't know the boundaries of the response.

Due to the data you displayed, also using specific format are irrelevant: `CSS/JQuery Extractor`, `XPath Extractor`, `JDBC PostProcessor` and `JSON Extractor`

`Result Status Action Handler` isn't extracting any value so it can't be used.

You remain with 2 options, use coding using `BeanShell PostProcessor` or
`JSR223 PostProcessor`

Or extract using a regular expression with [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor):

Choose Regular Expression [(.+)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match all line

> In Python and some other implementations (e.g. Java), the three common quantifiers (*, + and ?) are greedy by default because they match as many characters as possible.[32] The regex ".+" applied to the string
>
> matches the entire line

To return value in 1 variable use Template `$1$` and Match No. `1`

It will save your response in JMeter variable you will enter in `Name of created value`

In next requests use it as `${myVar}`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a regular expression to fetch the **entire** response body it would be something like:

```
(?s)(^.*)
```

Explanation:

- `()` = grouping
- `(?s)` = single line modifier
- `^` = line start
- `.` = wild-card character
- `*` = repetition

The relevant [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) Configuration would look like"

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `response`
- Regular Expression: `(?s)(^.*)`
- Template: `$1$`

You will be able to refer the extracted value as `${response}` where required.

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter)